# Apple ID wrong in screen time request message

Tags: screen-time

My son’s screen time request are all of a sudden coming though as a group message to me and my husband and it shows my sons name but my sisters Apple ID. We checked and his iPad is logged in to his Apple ID. Can anyone help?

Comment: I would start off with taking an inventory of the accounts in your family plan and the devices and their associated Apple IDs. Mare sure your son’s phone is signed into your son’s iCloud account.

Comment: Yes, we did this. His Apple ID is assigned correctly.

Comment: Is your sister part of the plan and is she identified as an Adult or Parent/Guardian?

Comment: No, she is not connected to our plan at all. We can’t figure out why his request say they come from her Apple ID

Comment: You might want to open a support ticket with Apple to document this, but I fear that they will tell you to “reinstall iOS.” This is something you can do yourself - disassociate the Apple ID with the device, then wipe completely.  Then reconnect the Apple ID.  Before doing this, I would go through the iCloud Account and make sure your sister’s name is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I have to admit, this is an interesting question!

Comment: Thanks! We will give that a try!